# jQuery clone with ajax autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

The achieved idea is an invoice, with fields item, description, rate, etc. Each line of fields, with a add row - achieved by jquery clone. And it is working.

However, I also have a working autocomplete, which gets the data from a database, and update the rest of the fields.

But I cant get the two to work together. I don't know how else to explain it.

So;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( "#label" ).autocomplete({
source: "<?=base_url()?>admin/autocomplete/",
minLength: 1,
select: function( event, ui ) {
event.preventDefault();

this.value = ui.item.valuedesc;
$('#label').val(ui.item.valuedesc);
$('#description').val(ui.item.description);
$('#rate').val(ui.item.rate);
}
});
});
</script>
```

Then the return I get is the valuedesc, description, rate, which then automatically updates the relevan fields.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="item_sku[]" data-required="1" class="form-control" id="label" autocomplete="off" required/>

<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="item_description[]" data-required="1" id="description" class="form-control" required/>

<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="item_amount[]" data-required="1" id="rate" class="form-control calculate" autocomplete="off" required/>
```

And this is what I use to clone the row and clears the input values of the newly added row

```
// add new product row on invoice
var cloned = $('#invoice_table tr:last').clone();
$(".add-row").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    cloned.clone().appendTo('#invoice_table').find('input').val('');
});
```

So, the autocomplete works for the first row - because I get the "label" id from the text input.

But if I add more, getting the autocomplete to work doesn't work, because of duplicate IDs.

My question would be thus; How can I dynamically add a unique ID to where "label" id currently is? Secondly, is it possible to alter the autocomplete javascript to prevent duplicating the javascript for each clone?

Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxFCN.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing it is to use classes instead of id-s:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="item_sku[]" data-required="1" class="form-control label" autocomplete="off" required/>
<!-- ... etc ... -->
```

and then initialise a new autocomplete every time you generate a new row:

```
$(function() {
    var options = {
        source: "<?=base_url()?>admin/autocomplete/",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            event.preventDefault();

            this.value = ui.item.valuedesc;
            $(this).val(ui.item.valuedesc);
            $(this).parents('tr').find('.description').val(ui.item.description);
            $(this).parents('tr').find('.rate').val(ui.item.rate);
        }
    };
    $( ".label" ).autocomplete(options);


    var cloned = $('#invoice_table tr:last').clone();
    $(".add-row").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        cloned.clone().appendTo('#invoice_table').find('input').val('')
                                                 .filter('.label').autocomplete(options);
    });
});
```

Comment: blgt, I value your reply - thank you. I've implemented your code and now the "label" field is gone when I refresh or when I click add more.

Comment: Looking at it again, I probably shouldn't've added the `.siblings('.label')`. I'll edit. This is more of a poc, don't edit it in directly. If it's still giving you problems, could you make a MCVE (eg. a fiddle)?

Comment: Thanx man. I'll wait for your edit, if I dont get it to work I'll try the MCVE

Comment: omg so sorry! My mistake. I have  a "label" class in css thats why it didnt show. Damn. So sorry. Okay it works with both before and after your edit. Works perfectly. The only thing is the rest of the fields doesnt update. But the autocomplete works everytime. Gee where do you guys get this knowledge.  http://i.share.pho.to/184eeec4_o.jpeg

Comment: Thanks to you this is what is working for me; The only think not working now is updating the relevant fields with the data: `this.value = ui.item.valuedesc;
  $(this).siblings('.item_sku').val(ui.item.valuedesc);
  $(this).siblings('.description').val(ui.item.description);
  $(this).siblings('.rate').val(ui.item.rate);
  }
  };
  $( ".item_sku" ).autocomplete(options);`

Comment: here is the jsfiddle - however I tried to simulate the json response and I cant. its in the js code. please will you have a look at at. http://jsfiddle.net/benniecpt/c5ajonav/

Comment: I assumed the `input` tags were the top-level elements, I see from the fiddle that is not the case. You can use `.parents()` and `.find()` instead of `.siblings()`, updating answer

Comment: omg - THANK YOU thank you thank you. It works and it works 10000%. So much thank you. Sending you n huge hug. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey just a question, for if you know. You've done so much already. If I accedently remove the one field. ie if there is only one line and I remove it by accident or purpose, and I hit ADD MORE again, it doesnt clone, because there is nothing to clone from. Can you perhaps point me into a direction to maybe to overcome this issue, or perhaps hide a default one somewhere and clone from that? Not sure. And not sure how to do the latter suggestion. If you know I'll appreciate your thoughts. thanx

Comment: I didn't think of that use case. What you had originally should work fine (an extra variable holding an additional clone). Edited into answer. Also, if this solves your problem consider [ticking it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)